# jQuery function parameter passing

Tags: jquery, function, parameter-passing

I try to call a function in jquery with parameter such that

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#id_pros').bind('change', wordCounter('id_pros_wordCountLabel') );
});

function wordCounter(item){
    ....
}
```

If I don't pass parameter `id_pros_wordCountLabel` it works great but now it didn't call wordCounter.

Which part is wrong with my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Bind expexts you to pass a reference to a function (or directly, a anonymous function) but instead you execute the function during the "bind" process, which returns undefined, so nothing is bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind()` expects a function argument, like this:

```
$('#id_pros').bind('change', wordCounter);
```

Note how there are no parentheses on `wordCounter`. This means that it's a reference to a function, and not an invocation of a function — which is what happens when you add parentheses. Use an anonymous function to solve the problem:

```
$('#id_pros').change(function ()
{
    wordCounter('id_pros_wordCountLabel');
});
```

(I also changed `.bind('change', ...)` to `.change(...)` which is equivalent but more concise.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#id_pros').bind('change', function() {
        wordCounter('id_pros_wordCountLabel');
    });
});
```

Your own code passes the *return value* of `wordCounter` (which is called on the spot, and not when the `change` event fires) to `bind`. `bind` expects to receive a function, and `wordCounter` probably returns something else, so when the `change` event fires you don't see anything happen.